# Changing hard coded path to variable in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables, import

Im using the following code and all works correctly

```
DECLARE @Directory varchar(100)
SELECT @Directory = 'c:\XML\'

DECLARE @FileExist int
DECLARE @FileName varchar(500),@DeleteCommand varchar(1000),@FullFileName varchar(500), @SQLFullFileName varchar(500)


DECLARE @X XML
SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,[ICECAT-interface],2)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\XML\1382.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS Import([ICECAT-interface])

select P1.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID,
       P2.X.value('@ID', 'int') as ProductID


 from @X.nodes('/ICECAT-interface/Product') as P1(X)
 cross apply P1.X.nodes('ProductRelated') as PR(X)
 cross apply PR.X.nodes('Product') as P2(X)
```

if i replace the line with the filename in C:\XML\1382.xml with this  line

```
 SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,[ICECAT-interface],2) 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + @FullFileName + ' ,SINGLE_BLOB) AS Import([ICECAT-interface])
```

it errors saying the file doesn't exist, but in debug mode i can see the variable @FullFileName exists and is correct.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

John

Comment: How is @FullFileName declared / populated?

Comment: Hi Aaron,   Ill edit the code as I cant paste it. 1 sec

Comment: Just to be clear, you are confirming that the file exists on the same machine that the SQL Server instance is running on correct?

Comment: Yes I am, I just wacked your code in and run my select statement on the xml output and it works a charm,  Thanks very much this has been driving me mad for hours..

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a variable to `OPENROWSET()` so you'll need to use dynamic SQL. This is untested but should give you an idea:

```sql
DECLARE @x XML, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,[ICECAT-interface],2) 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @FullFileName + ''' ,SINGLE_BLOB)
 ---------------------^^ escaped quotes are important 
 AS Import([ICECAT-interface]);';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@x XML OUTPUT', @x OUTPUT;

SELECT @x;
```