# SQL not concatenating?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I’m nearly a week old in SQL. I tried finding some answers in the net but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. I’m using SQL Server 2005.

```
USE devSSIS 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'VFPOLEDB', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE readDBF (
   @path nvarchar(1000) = '\\initial_loc\somesubfolder\',
   @name nvarchar(50) = 'initial_dbf')
AS
BEGIN
    select * 
    from openrowset('VFPOLEDB.1', '[@path]'; ''; '', 'select * from [@name]')
END
GO
```

Can someone help with this?

It says it has an error of:

> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Procedure readDBF, Line 6
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB.1" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: making a sp that i can run.
the exact functon of the sp is read many .dbf files with just 1 sp.
something like i can view another table next time i run this sp within the path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work, but I'm not an expert on foxpro and it's been a long time since I've had to use it.

What if you remove the quotes around the path variable and the brackets from @path and @name?

```
select * from openrowset('VFPOLEDB.1', @path; ''; '', 'select * from @name')
```

If that doesn't work, you could try the main command without creating the procedure.  In a new query, declare the variables and try the openrowset query.  Then wrap it back up in the create procedure syntax once it's working.

Comment: when i remove the quotes near '@path' is says
'Incorrect syntax near @path'
when i remove the quotes near '@name' it raises the original error
tnx for the suggestion though
^_^

Comment: No worries - sounds like you can not use a variable in openrowset.  You could try dynamic sql as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021730/changing-hard-coded-path-to-variable-in-ms-sql

Comment: ive tried what u suggested(tnx btw) but new error arise when i tried to put something
`USE devSSIS 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'VFPOLEDB', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE readDBF (
@path nvarchar(1000),
@name nvarchar(50),
@sql varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
set @sql = 'select * from openrowset(''VFPOLEDB.1'', ''' + @path +'''; ''; '', ''select * from ''' + @name + ''')'
END
GO`
this code runs w/o error
but when i add this
`exec @sql`
it says `must declare scalar variable @sql`
any suggestion?

Comment: Probably a bit late now but, that error indicates you forgot to declare a variable before using it: DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Another thing to beware of is the scope of that variable with all those GO commands.  When you issue GO, it runs everything in that script up to that point and then forgets about any variables you already declared along with their values before continuing with the rest of the script

Comment: tnx it works!
already "compiled"(don't know the right word for sql) but when i execute it, it gives errors,
1) when i dont put anything on the param `@sql` and says
`Procedure or Function 'readDBF' expects parameter '@sql', which was not supplied.`
2) when i pass the `@sql` as null it says
`Could not find stored procedure 'select * from openrowset('VFPOLEDB.1', '\\server\path\another_path\'; '; ', 'select * from 'DBFname')'.`
any suggestions? i'd gladly take it

Comment: Your welcome.  Some sort of validation to make sure you don't call it with nulls?

Comment: uhm... can you please be more specific?
i probably dont know how to validate it to make sure i doesn't call with null

Comment: i really dont get what you mean
but after thinking about my code, shouldn't the `@sql` have a value since  already put something in it, or `set` have a different function than to put some variable in a parameter?

Comment: Probably best if you ask another question using your revised code.  Someone may be able to help.

Comment: so when asking for another question form another question doesn't count as dup?
if thats it then im of to ask some help
tnx btw for many suggestion that are really helpful